# Should I choose asyncio over gevents to achieve parallel processing in Python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, gevent

The task is to run multiple UNIX grep commands on log files using subprocess module at the same time. Running these grep commands synchronously is time consuming and hence want to parallelize the same.

Grep commands that I want to run in parallel:

```
grep "start" /var/log/application/start.log.gz
grep "end" /var/log/application/end.log.gz
grep "proceed" /var/log/application/proceed.log.gz
```

Should I choose to use asyncio or opt for gevents?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *Should I choose to use `asyncio` or opt for `gevents`?*

Well, better neither one. Why to **pay the extra costs three times** *(?)* if can have the `parallel` run it?

If there exists an indeed reasonable motivation for such tasks to get launched but ALAP and concurrently ( i.e. under one common shared "ceiling" for disk-I/O and mem-I/O throughput ), yet with minimum overhead add-on costs - measure them, before downvoting without having the hard facts in hand ( right, python process-based execution comes at a huge --**not anything near a few `[us]`**-- add-on costs of process-instantiation, the worse in Windows-class O/S, where a full copy of the whole python interpreter state, incl. its all variables, objects and all their memory-rich data-structures, was first to get re-created for each sub-process (do read the `multiprocessing` documentation details on process-based parallelism and about additional consistency risks, for which `fork` instantiation method started to be considered unsafe on O/S that permit it ( not all do in 2020-Q1 ) )

Better try using rather but one process with the just-enough, right-designed, smart and well-tuned tool for doing the very that at once, in parallel, the gnu `parallel` ( best start with reading the `man parallel` for all the ready-to use `parallel` job-submission options configurables )

**Example :**

> *Grep commands that I want to run in parallel:*

Python can launch but this and handle the log and outputs accordingly, as needed

```
  parallel --jobs 3           \
           --halt now,fail=1   \
           --joblog LastRUN.log \
      grep {} /var/log/application/{}.log.gz ::: start proceed end
```

will result in equally processed

```
grep "start"   /var/log/application/start.log.gz
grep "end"     /var/log/application/end.log.gz
grep "proceed" /var/log/application/proceed.log.gz
```

( plus may serve it with more comfort on how to handle failed cases, logged outputs etc. )

Comment: Even though this seems to be a possible solution, I am trying to achieve parallelism in the Python language instead of running a shell command that executes in parallel. Anyway, thanks for this approach. Will come in handy for a use case later.

Comment: I ended up using the multiprocessing module in python to achieve this as system resource wasn't a problem.